# Edit OSM ways via shapely, add some nodes, write back to OSM xml

Tags: python, xml, openstreetmap, shapely

Hi I was googling around to find some hints to implement this process chain entirely in python  (without using a postgis db, osmosis etc):

1. Read ways geometries from OSM xml to shapely

(for this I could use [imposm.parser](http://imposm.org/docs/imposm.parser/latest/) or sth else, shouldnt be a problem)

2. Add some nodes to some ways

   - I can find the geometries of those additional nodes according to my requirements via shapely
   - I need to add some tags to those new nodes

3._ I need to write all the additions back to the original (or a copy of the old) OSM xml file

I got stuck particularly at the point adding my new nodes to the OSM XML   and writing it back to OSM XML

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide us more details and tell us where you are stuck exactly?

Comment: 1) what about optionally importing the ways directly from OSM into python using the osmapi? If not, then use Python's Etree to parse the XML by using OSM's XML schema. 2) Use Shapely and optionally also GeoPandas to modify your geometry. 3) Use the OSM schema to then output XML using Etree again (or lxml).